# How to fix the np.cumsum function when mapping a series with regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, nlp

I have a list like:

```
**x** 
Chapter 1 
some text
Chapter 2
Chapter 3
Chapter 4
Chapter 5"
```

The output I look for is a series like:

```
1
1
2
3
4
5
```

I wrote this code

```
pattern = r"chapter \d" 
x.map(lambda x: np.cumsum(bool(re.search(pattern,str(x), flags=re.I))))
```

It gives me the output:

```
[1]
[0]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]
```

Can you guys help me fix this code? You can also suggest a better solution to go about it. Thanks

Comment: i did fix my code doing it in 2 steps:
```pattern = r"chapter \d" 
y = x.map(lambda x: bool(re.search(pattern,str(x), flags=re.I)))
z = np.cumsum(y)```
But still cannot figure out why the single liner didnt work

Comment: You can add your own answer with your solution if that's what you decided to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for helping me fix my code. I did see an alternative solution using ffill which was great.

I used a 2 liner solution below:

```
pattern = r"chapter \d" 
y = x.map(lambda x: bool(re.search(pattern,str(x), flags=re.I))) 
z = np.cumsum(y)
```